# How to use a button while also using a DataModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating an application in WPF using MVVM. I have a tab called tab1, which is a UserControl and has an associated DataModel (but no View, and thus, no ViewModel). Within tab1's content, there is a ListView, inside which is a button. The problem is that I would like the button to work. It worked when tab1 had an associated Tab1ViewModel, but I am told it *must* have a DataModel and not a ViewModel. I don't believe DataModels can support commands, so does anyone know of a workaround for this? Or does there really just need to be a ViewModel for any nested control with buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having a view-model associated with the view is "kind of" against the guidelines of MVVM.
I can think about two solutions :

1. If you are "allowed", you can inherit the DataModel and add some
   "ViewModel functionality" (Like the button's command)
2. If you are "allowed", have a view-model that contains the data-model (in this method you lose the ability to listen property changes if bind your view to the nested data-model fields)
3. Add the event handler in view's code-behind (which is against the MVVM's guidelines)

These two solutions aren't that great so I suggest that you try to solve the issue that leads to the facts that you can't use a view-model with your view and solve that.

Comment: "which is a UserControl and has an associated DataModel (but **no View**, and thus, no ViewModel). " It's not a view; it's a user control, _within_ a view. And yeah, I'm not going to be adding any code-behind since it's against MVVM as you said

Comment: IMO, when it come to MVVM , a user control is a view as well and should have a view-model bounded to it.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to agree, but the people in charge of me don't. I'll look into your 1st and new 2nd bullets tomorrow, thanks